# Cannot send data into another method

Tags: java, mysql

I encounter a problem in transferring information from one class to another. For example, my second class file will read a csv file and extract data into an array, nextLine[]. The data is then transferred to another array d. The function then call the readDateBase, which will accept the array input, d and perform the set string function. However, I have been encountering an error that prevents me from sending the data into the function readDataBase(d); I'm not sure why...could someone help me out here? Thanks alot!

```
public void readDataBase(String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4 ) throws Exception   {
try {
// This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Setup the connection with the DB
connect = DriverManager
.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MAXdb?"
+ "user=root&password=");

// Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
statement = connect.createStatement();
// Result set get the result of the SQL query
resultSet = statement
.executeQuery("select * from MAXdb.emcsg");
writeResultSet(resultSet);

// PreparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");

// Parameters start with 1

preparedStatement.setString(1, d1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, d2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, d3);
preparedStatement.setString(4, d4);

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("SELECT  Date, Time, Demand, Supply, Price from MAXdb.emcsg");
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
writeResultSet(resultSet);
    }
```

My second class:

```
public void Csvreader() throws IOException {
try {
// TODO code application logic here

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:/chart.csv"));

String  nextLine[];
Mysql sen = new Mysql();
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

sen.readDataBase(nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3]);
}


} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Opencsv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your readDatabase() method accepts a `String[]` as a parameter, and you're passing it a `String`.

If you use an IDE such as Eclipse, the IDE will throw up an error message and highlight the call, saying that it's invalid.  (Also, try reading the error message!  If you can't make sense of it, post the error message as well.)a

And be careful with your terminology.  Your error was *not* that you didn't catch the exception, it's that your logic would *always* raise it.  Catching it wouldn't make your program run, it would just cause it to fail silently.

Comment: I'm using netbeans, it shows sen.readDataBase(nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3]); highlighted with an error.

Comment: If there is a compilation error, NetBeans must also show the error message in some "Errors", "Problems" or "Compiler" view (I haven't used Netbeans for a while). Find this view, read the message, and try to understand its meaning. Error messages are intended to be read.

Comment: Ok...I found my mistake =.= I didn't catch exception. Sorry about that!